# Truffle react box onChange error: cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

Tags: react, truffle-box

these are the functions that fail:
Error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
    at createOrgSchoolAddress (App.js:187)

when I pasted the address in (third function was called)

```
createOrgShortNameChange(event){
    this.setState({createCredentialOrgShortName: event.target.value});
}
createOrgOfficialNameChange(event){
    this.setState({createCredentialOrgOfficialSchoolName: event.target.value});
}
createOrgSchoolAddress(event){
    this.setState({createCredentialOrgSchoolAddress: event.target.value});
}
```

[GitHug Link](https://github.com/shaddow1201/CredentialVerify)

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr><td>School Short Name</td><td><input type="text" maxLength="30" size="32" value={this.state.createCredentialOrgShortName} onChange={this.createOrgShortNameChange} /></td></tr>  
    <tr><td>School Official Name</td><td><input type="text" maxLength="70" size="72" value={this.state.createCredentialOrgOfficialSchoolName} onChange={this.createOrgOfficialNameChange} /></td></tr>  
    <tr><td>School Address</td><td><input type="text" maxLength="42"  size="50" value={this.state.createCredentialOrgSchoolAddress} onChange={this.createOrgSchoolAddress} /></td></tr>  
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I expect it's something simple, but am stuck at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

per: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32317154/react-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-setstate-of-undefined

it suggested i add the binds at the top (which didn't work), but putting them in place worked well.

```
<tr><td>School Short Name</td><td><input type="text" maxLength="30"  size="32" value={this.state.createCredentialOrgShortName} onChange={this.createOrgShortNameChange.bind(this)} /></td></tr>  
<tr><td>School Official Name</td><td><input type="text" maxLength="70"  size="72" value={this.state.createCredentialOrgOfficialSchoolName} onChange={this.createOrgOfficialNameChange.bind(this)} /></td></tr>  
<tr><td>School Address</td><td><input type="text" maxLength="42"  size="50" value={this.state.createCredentialOrgSchoolAddress} onChange={this.createOrgSchoolAddress.bind(this)} /></td></tr>
```